# SQL Server to mySQL converter

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database, data-migration

Hai Techies,

I have some stored procedure which was written in SQL server.Now i want to migrate this to mysql.Is there any freeware tools which can do this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. You could just execute the query to create the procedure, ie:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Blah(foo int, bar text)

END;
```

(I think) and then ask questions or Google any problems that occur.

Answer (score 0):

There is a toolkit for data migration, available [at this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/index.html), but you might have to handle stored procedures manually. Another suggestion, that if you can find a conversion tool to move the SP's to DB2 you may have an easier time, as MySQL procedures are close to DB2 in style.

Comment: The migration tool kit has reached EOL.  They are now pushing the workbench but it is not as simple to use as the old toolkit...
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/